# XSS prevention of user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tag-it

I am trying to implement a XSS prevention function into my code. I have a php XSS function that works very well and a javascript side one for elements that are not sent to the database right away. The problem is that during my own tests, I am able to "break" my code by inputing something similar to

> "/> Breaking the code is easier than it should be

I hope that is clear what this could be a problem. I am using resource called "tag-it", which you can check out [here](https://github.com/fagianijunior/tag-it).

*by the way this is a branch from the main project that supposedly fixed the issue of not working with jQuery 3, but it wasn't implemented. I have fixed it though by doing what the commit comment said to do which is     replace `.andSelf()` with `.addBack()`*

I currently have a lot more code than would be helpful to put here, so I am going to put a simpler example code snippet below.

```js
/*--------tag-it.js (fixed for jQuery 3--------*/
/*--------Must be placed first to allow for proper functionality--------*/
(function(b) {
  b.widget("ui.tagit", {
    options: {
      allowDuplicates: !1,
      caseSensitive: !0,
      fieldName: "tags",
      placeholderText: null,
      readOnly: !1,
      removeConfirmation: !1,
      tagLimit: null,
      availableTags: [],
      autocomplete: {},
      showAutocompleteOnFocus: !1,
      allowSpaces: !1,
      singleField: !1,
      singleFieldDelimiter: ",",
      singleFieldNode: null,
      animate: !0,
      tabIndex: null,
      beforeTagAdded: null,
      afterTagAdded: null,
      beforeTagRemoved: null,
      afterTagRemoved: null,
      onTagClicked: null,
      onTagLimitExceeded: null,
      onTagAdded: null,
      onTagRemoved: null,
      tagSource: null
    },
    _create: function() {
      var a =
        this;
      this.element.is("input") ? (this.tagList = b("<ul></ul>").insertAfter(this.element), this.options.singleField = !0, this.options.singleFieldNode = this.element, this.element.addClass("tagit-hidden-field")) : this.tagList = this.element.find("ul, ol").addBack().last();
      this.tagInput = b('<input type="text" />').addClass("ui-widget-content");
      this.options.readOnly && this.tagInput.attr("disabled", "disabled");
      this.options.tabIndex && this.tagInput.attr("tabindex", this.options.tabIndex);
      this.options.placeholderText && this.tagInput.attr("placeholder",
        this.options.placeholderText);
      this.options.autocomplete.source || (this.options.autocomplete.source = function(a, e) {
        var d = a.term.toLowerCase(),
          c = b.grep(this.options.availableTags, function(a) {
            return 0 === a.toLowerCase().indexOf(d)
          });
        this.options.allowDuplicates || (c = this._subtractArray(c, this.assignedTags()));
        e(c)
      });
      this.options.showAutocompleteOnFocus && (this.tagInput.focus(function(b, d) {
        a._showAutocomplete()
      }), "undefined" === typeof this.options.autocomplete.minLength && (this.options.autocomplete.minLength =
        0));
      b.isFunction(this.options.autocomplete.source) && (this.options.autocomplete.source = b.proxy(this.options.autocomplete.source, this));
      b.isFunction(this.options.tagSource) && (this.options.tagSource = b.proxy(this.options.tagSource, this));
      this.tagList.addClass("tagit").addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all").append(b('<li class="tagit-new"></li>').append(this.tagInput)).click(function(d) {
        var c = b(d.target);
        c.hasClass("tagit-label") ? (c = c.closest(".tagit-choice"), c.hasClass("removed") || a._trigger("onTagClicked",
          d, {
            tag: c,
            tagLabel: a.tagLabel(c)
          })) : a.tagInput.focus()
      });
      var c = !1;
      if (this.options.singleField)
        if (this.options.singleFieldNode) {
          var d = b(this.options.singleFieldNode),
            f = d.val().split(this.options.singleFieldDelimiter);
          d.val("");
          b.each(f, function(b, d) {
            a.createTag(d, null, !0);
            c = !0
          })
        } else this.options.singleFieldNode = b('<input type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="" name="' + this.options.fieldName + '" />'), this.tagList.after(this.options.singleFieldNode);
      c || this.tagList.children("li").each(function() {
        b(this).hasClass("tagit-new") ||
          (a.createTag(b(this).text(), b(this).attr("class"), !0), b(this).remove())
      });
      this.tagInput.keydown(function(c) {
        if (c.which == b.ui.keyCode.BACKSPACE && "" === a.tagInput.val()) {
          var d = a._lastTag();
          !a.options.removeConfirmation || d.hasClass("remove") ? a.removeTag(d) : a.options.removeConfirmation && d.addClass("remove ui-state-highlight")
        } else a.options.removeConfirmation && a._lastTag().removeClass("remove ui-state-highlight");
        if (c.which === b.ui.keyCode.COMMA && !1 === c.shiftKey || c.which === b.ui.keyCode.ENTER || c.which ==
          b.ui.keyCode.TAB && "" !== a.tagInput.val() || c.which == b.ui.keyCode.SPACE && !0 !== a.options.allowSpaces && ('"' != b.trim(a.tagInput.val()).replace(/^s*/, "").charAt(0) || '"' == b.trim(a.tagInput.val()).charAt(0) && '"' == b.trim(a.tagInput.val()).charAt(b.trim(a.tagInput.val()).length - 1) && 0 !== b.trim(a.tagInput.val()).length - 1)) c.which === b.ui.keyCode.ENTER && "" === a.tagInput.val() || c.preventDefault(), a.options.autocomplete.autoFocus && a.tagInput.data("autocomplete-open") || (a.tagInput.autocomplete("close"), a.createTag(a._cleanedInput()))
      }).blur(function(b) {
        a.tagInput.data("autocomplete-open") ||
          a.createTag(a._cleanedInput())
      });
      if (this.options.availableTags || this.options.tagSource || this.options.autocomplete.source) d = {
        select: function(b, c) {
          a.createTag(c.item.value);
          return !1
        }
      }, b.extend(d, this.options.autocomplete), d.source = this.options.tagSource || d.source, this.tagInput.autocomplete(d).bind("autocompleteopen.tagit", function(b, c) {
        a.tagInput.data("autocomplete-open", !0)
      }).bind("autocompleteclose.tagit", function(b, c) {
        a.tagInput.data("autocomplete-open", !1)
      }), this.tagInput.autocomplete("widget").addClass("tagit-autocomplete")
    },
    destroy: function() {
      b.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
      this.element.unbind(".tagit");
      this.tagList.unbind(".tagit");
      this.tagInput.removeData("autocomplete-open");
      this.tagList.removeClass("tagit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all tagit-hidden-field");
      this.element.is("input") ? (this.element.removeClass("tagit-hidden-field"), this.tagList.remove()) : (this.element.children("li").each(function() {
        b(this).hasClass("tagit-new") ? b(this).remove() : (b(this).removeClass("tagit-choice ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all remove tagit-choice-editable tagit-choice-read-only"),
          b(this).text(b(this).children(".tagit-label").text()))
      }), this.singleFieldNode && this.singleFieldNode.remove());
      return this
    },
    _cleanedInput: function() {
      return b.trim(this.tagInput.val().replace(/^"(.*)"$/, "$1"))
    },
    _lastTag: function() {
      return this.tagList.find(".tagit-choice:last:not(.removed)")
    },
    _tags: function() {
      return this.tagList.find(".tagit-choice:not(.removed)")
    },
    assignedTags: function() {
      var a = this,
        c = [];
      this.options.singleField ? (c = b(this.options.singleFieldNode).val().split(this.options.singleFieldDelimiter),
        "" === c[0] && (c = [])) : this._tags().each(function() {
        c.push(a.tagLabel(this))
      });
      return c
    },
    _updateSingleTagsField: function(a) {
      b(this.options.singleFieldNode).val(a.join(this.options.singleFieldDelimiter)).trigger("change")
    },
    _subtractArray: function(a, c) {
      for (var d = [], f = 0; f < a.length; f++) - 1 == b.inArray(a[f], c) && d.push(a[f]);
      return d
    },
    tagLabel: function(a) {
      return this.options.singleField ? b(a).find(".tagit-label:first").text() : b(a).find("input:first").val()
    },
    _showAutocomplete: function() {
      this.tagInput.autocomplete("search",
        "")
    },
    _findTagByLabel: function(a) {
      var c = this,
        d = null;
      this._tags().each(function(f) {
        if (c._formatStr(a) == c._formatStr(c.tagLabel(this))) return d = b(this), !1
      });
      return d
    },
    _isNew: function(a) {
      return !this._findTagByLabel(a)
    },
    _formatStr: function(a) {
      return this.options.caseSensitive ? a : b.trim(a.toLowerCase())
    },
    _effectExists: function(a) {
      return Boolean(b.effects && (b.effects[a] || b.effects.effect && b.effects.effect[a]))
    },
    createTag: function(a, c, d) {
      var f = this;
      a = b.trim(a);
      this.options.preprocessTag && (a = this.options.preprocessTag(a));
      if ("" === a) return !1;
      if (!this.options.allowDuplicates && !this._isNew(a)) return a = this._findTagByLabel(a), !1 !== this._trigger("onTagExists", null, {
        existingTag: a,
        duringInitialization: d
      }) && this._effectExists("highlight") && a.effect("highlight"), !1;
      if (this.options.tagLimit && this._tags().length >= this.options.tagLimit) return this._trigger("onTagLimitExceeded", null, {
        duringInitialization: d
      }), !1;
      var g = b(this.options.onTagClicked ? '<a class="tagit-label"></a>' : '<span class="tagit-label"></span>').text(a),
        e = b("<li></li>").addClass("tagit-choice ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all").addClass(c).append(g);
      this.options.readOnly ? e.addClass("tagit-choice-read-only") : (e.addClass("tagit-choice-editable"), c = b("<span></span>").addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-close"), c = b('<a><span class="text-icon">\u00d7</span></a>').addClass("tagit-close").append(c).click(function(a) {
        f.removeTag(e)
      }), e.append(c));
      this.options.singleField || (g = g.html(), e.append('<input type="hidden" value="' + g + '" name="' + this.options.fieldName + '" class="tagit-hidden-field" />'));
      !1 !== this._trigger("beforeTagAdded", null, {
        tag: e,
        tagLabel: this.tagLabel(e),
        duringInitialization: d
      }) && (this.options.singleField && (g = this.assignedTags(), g.push(a), this._updateSingleTagsField(g)), this._trigger("onTagAdded", null, e), this.tagInput.val(""), this.tagInput.parent().before(e), this._trigger("afterTagAdded", null, {
        tag: e,
        tagLabel: this.tagLabel(e),
        duringInitialization: d
      }), this.options.showAutocompleteOnFocus && !d && setTimeout(function() {
        f._showAutocomplete()
      }, 0))
    },
    removeTag: function(a, c) {
      c = "undefined" === typeof c ? this.options.animate : c;
      a = b(a);
      this._trigger("onTagRemoved",
        null, a);
      if (!1 !== this._trigger("beforeTagRemoved", null, {
          tag: a,
          tagLabel: this.tagLabel(a)
        })) {
        if (this.options.singleField) {
          var d = this.assignedTags(),
            f = this.tagLabel(a),
            d = b.grep(d, function(a) {
              return a != f
            });
          this._updateSingleTagsField(d)
        }
        if (c) {
          a.addClass("removed");
          var d = this._effectExists("blind") ? ["blind", {
              direction: "horizontal"
            }, "fast"] : ["fast"],
            g = this;
          d.push(function() {
            a.remove();
            g._trigger("afterTagRemoved", null, {
              tag: a,
              tagLabel: g.tagLabel(a)
            })
          });
          a.fadeOut("fast").hide.apply(a, d).dequeue()
        } else a.remove(),
          this._trigger("afterTagRemoved", null, {
            tag: a,
            tagLabel: this.tagLabel(a)
          })
      }
    },
    removeTagByLabel: function(a, b) {
      var d = this._findTagByLabel(a);
      if (!d) throw "No such tag exists with the name '" + a + "'";
      this.removeTag(d, b)
    },
    removeAll: function() {
      var a = this;
      this._tags().each(function(b, d) {
        a.removeTag(d, !1)
      })
    }
  })
})(jQuery);

/*--------My example JS--------*/
// Create the tag "box"
let tagBox = $('#tagMe');
tagBox.tagit();

//Html escape function
function htmlEscape(str) {
  return str
    .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
    .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
    .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

```css
/*-------- Default Tag-it Stylesheet (altered)--------*/

ul.tagit {
  padding: 1px 5px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 0 8px;
  margin-left: inherit;
  margin-right: inherit
}

ul.tagit li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px 5px 2px 0
}

input.tagit-hidden-field,
ul.tagit li.tagit-choice .tagit-close .text-icon {
  display: none
}

ul.tagit li.tagit-choice {
  position: relative;
  line-height: inherit
}

ul.tagit li.tagit-choice-read-only {
  padding: .2em .5em
}

ul.tagit li.tagit-choice-editable {
  padding: .2em 18px .2em .5em
}

ul.tagit li.tagit-new {
  padding: .25em 4px .25em 0
}

ul.tagit li.tagit-choice a.tagit-label {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none
}

ul.tagit li.tagit-choice .tagit-close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: .1em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -8px;
  line-height: 17px
}

ul.tagit li.tagit-choice input {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px 5px 2px 0
}

ul.tagit input[type=text] {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  width: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  outline: 0
}


/*--------My Example Custom Theming--------*/

ul.tagit {
  padding: 1px 5px;
  border: solid thin green;
}

ul.tagit li.tagit-choice {
  border: solid thin #6aa1cc;
  background: #dafaff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: inherit;
}

.ui-icon-close:after {
  content: "\00d7";
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ui-icon-close {
  padding: 4px 4px;
}

.ui-icon-close:hover {
  color: #e74c18;
}

.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
  display: none !important;
}

kbd {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form>
  <p>Type in a single word without spaces (I haven't enabled input with spaces in this example), then press comma, tab, or enter.</p>
  <ul id="tagMe"></ul>
  <p>After you have a tag, inspect the tag element, especially the hidden input that is generated below it. If you put in a none XSS string, you will see that string has been placed inside the value attribute of that input element. BUT if you put an XSS
    string like <kbd>&quot;/&gt; Breakingbad</kbd> then you see that the string has broken out of the value attribute. I have also inluded a function that I have been trying to find a place where it works in the tag-it.js but haven't had success yet.</p>
</form>
```

*Edit*
I originally put the wrong function for html escape into the JS, I have corrected that.